# Firefox why window.opener is defined even for a new tab

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox3.6, window.opener

I am porting quite old corp application from IE to Firefox. Here is my situation.

User goes away from computer for a while and his session becomes expired.

When user tries to access something in popup, he is being redirected to login page (in popup window). In login page onload event popup window chain is being closed and root page refreshed (in root page tab user is redirected to login page).

The guy before me wrote this like this: if window.top.opener is undefined, we're not in popup. It worked fine in IE but I am getting non-stoppable refresh in Firefox.

Why in Firefox window.opener is still defined and points to same window,
even if this is a new tab, not popup?
How should I correctly determine that current window is popup?

Comment: From the perspective of the DOM, there's no difference between opening in a new window, or a new tab. It's just a UI difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not open new windows. Use some layers on page to show that message. Look at [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or something like that.

Comment: I definetly should take your advice, but unfortunatly I just cannot rewrite entire app (popups in my case are not just popups but separate fully functional windows)